# Expressing a Gaussian-like integral in terms of error function, faliure of Glasser's master theorem?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, error-function

So I have this integral $$
I=\int_0^c\exp\left(-a^2x^2-\frac{b^2}{x^2}\right)\,dx, \quad(a,b>0)
$$
This is what I tried to write it in terms of error function.
$$
I=e^{-2ab}\int_0^c\exp\left(-a^2\left(x-\frac{b}{ax}\right)^2\right)\,dx
$$
By [Glasser's master theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html)
$$
I=e^{2ab}\int_0^ce^{-a^2x^2}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi e^{2ab}}{2a}\text{erf}(ac)
$$
But according to eq 5 [here](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73b/jresv73bn1p1_a1b.pdf) the correct answer is
$$
I=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{4a}(e^{2ab}\text{erf}(ax+b/x)+e^{-2ab}\text{erf}(ax-b/x))
$$ 
What went wrong here and how to get the correct answer?

Comment: upper and lower bounds of the integral after substitution should be changed.

Comment: @Nosrati Doing that I got one erfc not 2 erf s. Would you mind writing down an answer? I'll vote and accept.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: In Glasser's master theorem, bounds of integration are from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, or am I missing something? Also, those are indefinite

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin But you can always assume that the integrand vanishes elsewhere.

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife then $x-\frac{1}{x} \in (0, c)$, so bounds must change.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin Yeah, but changing it I got only one erfc. (Not the one I've posted. That's incorrect of course.)

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife I think it's because $x-\frac{b}{ax}$ isn't one-to-one, you probably neglected this fact. I also meant this function in the other comment

Comment: Clearly the correct answer cannot depend on $x$. Did you mean $c$ instead of $x$?

Comment: @uniquesolution it depends on $x$ because it's indefinite, op didn't substitute the limits of integration. Look in the link provided by the op

Comment: The way to get the correct answer is to manipulate the expression $(ax+b/x)^2$.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin  I am afraid that $I$ is a function of $a,b,c$, not of $x$.

Comment: @uniquesolution wrong about? I'm saying the integral that op wrote (in the bottom of the question) is indefinite. I'm aware it must depend on $a, b, c$. You simply misunderstood.

Comment: You are wrong when you say that it depends on $x$. It does not. You are also wrong when you say that the integral the op wrote is indefinite. It is definite.

Comment: I'm not saying that. Why be so stubborn?

Comment: You said above "it depends on $x$ because..." . I am not stubborn, I am just trying to be accurate on a mathematics site.

Comment: No, I tried explaining to you why what op wrote depends on $x$. I'm not saying that the integral does, but what he wrote does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality we can assume $c>0$ , since $c<0$ only changes the sign of the integral.

As already discussed in the comments, Glasser's master theorem does not apply here. We can instead write the integral as
$$ I = \mathrm{e}^{2ab} \int \limits_0^c \mathrm{e}^{-(a x + b/x)^2} \, \mathrm{d} x \, .$$

Now we would like to let $a x + b/x = t$ . Since this map is not bijective, we need to be careful here! For $0<x<\sqrt{b/a}$ the correct inverse is 
$$x = \frac{1}{2a} \left(t-\sqrt{t^2-4ab}\right) \, ,$$
while for $x > \sqrt{b/a}$ we have to use
$$x = \frac{1}{2a} \left(t+\sqrt{t^2-4ab}\right) \, .$$

---

For $c \leq \sqrt{b/a} \, \Leftrightarrow \, a c - b/c \leq 0$ we only need the first version. The substitution yields
$$ I = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{2ab}}{2a} \int \limits_{ac+b/c}^\infty \left[\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2-4ab}} - 1\right]\mathrm{e}^{-t^2} \, \mathrm{d} t \, . $$
Changing variables once more for the first part ($u = \sqrt{t^2 - 4ab}$) and using the complementary error function $\operatorname{erfc} = 1-\operatorname{erf}$ we obtain
$$ I = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4a} \left[\mathrm{e}^{-2ab} \operatorname{erfc}(|ac - b/c|) - \mathrm{e}^{2ab} \operatorname{erfc}(ac + b/c)\right] \, .$$

---

For $c > \sqrt{b/a} \, \Leftrightarrow \, a c - b/c > 0$ we have to split the integral:
\begin{align}
I &= \mathrm{e}^{2ab} \left\{\int \limits_0^\sqrt{b/a} \mathrm{e}^{-(a x + b/x)^2} \, \mathrm{d} x +  \int \limits_\sqrt{b/a}^c \mathrm{e}^{-(a x + b/x)^2} \, \mathrm{d} x \right\} \\
&= \frac{\mathrm{e}^{2ab}}{2a} \left\{\int \limits_{2\sqrt{ab}}^\infty \left[\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2-4ab}} - 1\right]\mathrm{e}^{-t^2} \, \mathrm{d} t + \int \limits_{2\sqrt{ab}}^{ac+b/c} \left[1 + \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2-4ab}}\right]\mathrm{e}^{-t^2} \, \mathrm{d} t \right\} \, .
\end{align}
Evaluating the remaining integrals as in the other case we find
$$ I = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4a} \left[\mathrm{e}^{-2ab} [1+\operatorname{erf}(ac - b/c)] - \mathrm{e}^{2ab} \operatorname{erfc}(ac + b/c)\right] \, .$$

---

Both results can be simplified and the final result for arbitrary $c>0$ is
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4a} \left[\mathrm{e}^{-2ab} \operatorname{erfc}(b/c - ac) - \mathrm{e}^{2ab} \operatorname{erfc}(b/c + ac)\right] \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4a} \left[\mathrm{e}^{2ab} \operatorname{erf}(ac+b/c) + \mathrm{e}^{-2ab} \operatorname{erf}(ac-b/c) - 2 \sinh(2ab)\right] \, ,
\end{align}
which agrees with the result from the table (except for a constant, of course). Letting $c \to \infty$ we obtain the integral
$$ \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-a^2 x^2 - b^2 /x^2} \, \mathrm{d} x = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{a} \mathrm{e}^{-2ab} \, , $$
which can also be computed using the master theorem.